# Using pytest and SonarQube, How can I cover code in an if statement that circumstantially can't be reached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, code-coverage

An illustrative simplified example of the problem

```
import datetime

def func(value):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.month < 7:
        out = value
    else:
        out = value + 1
    return out

# fails half the year
def test_func():
    a=func(4)
    assert a==4

# works but only covers one half of the branch based on month.
def test_func2():
    a=func(4)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.month < 7:
        assert a==4
    else:
        assert a==5
```

How do I create a current-date agnostic single test that covers both branches of the if?
I've tried various experiments with the mock library, and patching, with limited success, and even where apparently successful, the code coverage still wasn't complete, presumably because the test was being conducted on a mocked object.

I'm very new to unit testing and pytest in particular, I think the question I'm asking is, is there a way to somehow "override" a value in a function (in this case, "now") where it can't be influenced by function parameters, and also obtain code coverage?

Comment: Why not passing `now` to `func(value, now)`? In case of `datetime.datetime.now()` you can temporary change systems date and time in your test function, but this makes not much sense to me. If you check for computers processor, graphic card, operating system, etc. it will be harder to force system calls to return the desired test response compared to changing date and time. And ... I don't know if it can be done what you (probably) ask for. I see it this way: "In a permanent total darkness you can't check proper function of a light detector."

Comment: @Claudio thanks for the suggestion, sadly in the real scenario the function is much more complex and called from multiple places which makes altering it non-viable (certainly when weighed against a small % increase in code coverage).

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that will patch datetime.now for you, like freezegun.

Comment: thanks for the hint / clue, I'll see if i can make it lead somewhere